# Сделать из двух массивов один javascript

Tags: javascript

Есть два массива:

```
order = [
{id:1, product_id=100},
{id:2, product_id=200},
];

product = [
{id:100, key: xxxxxx},
{id:200, key: yyyyyy},
]
```

Как из них сделать один вида:

```
order = [
    {id:1, product_id=100, key: xxxxxx},
    {id:2, product_id=200, key: yyyyyy},
    ];
```

Comment: А какое условие объединения?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно создать словарик `product`-ов, чтобы лишний раз не бегать по массиву, а потом заполнить данными позиции заказа.

```js
const order = [
  {id: 1, product_id: 100},
  {id: 2, product_id: 200},
];

const product = [
  {id: 100, key: 'xxxxxx'},
  {id: 200, key: 'yyyyyy'},
];

const productDict = product.reduce((acc, x) => {
  const { id, ...rest } = x;
  acc[id] = rest;
  return acc;
}, {});


const fillOrder = order.map((x) =>
  Object.assign({}, x, productDict[x.product_id]));

console.log(fillOrder);
```

---

Мой опыт подсказывает, что удобнее будет работать с конструкцией вида

> {id: 1, product_id: 100, Product: {id: 100, key: 'xxxxxx'}}

вместо `{id: 1, product_id: 100, key: 'xxxxxx'}`.